# PHP - Upload video to specific Facebook album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm facing some issues with PHP Facebook SDK and the upload of a video to a Facebook page.

I explain you: the video is uploaded correctly, but I want to insert it in a specific Facebook album. I think that the problem and also the solution is in these lines.

Moreover, the video is always uploaded in the Page Photos section and not in the Videos section.

How do I upload the video to a specific album or in the Videos section?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'POST', '/{PAGE-ID}/videos', array(
    'source' => new CURLFile($pathtofile.$name, 'video/mp4'),
    'title' => basename($name, ".mp4")
```

**EDIT**

I edited my code in this way, using the cURL library, but the problem is still the same: the video is uploaded into the Photo section.

Is there a way to upload it into the Video album?

```
$attachment = array(
        'access_token'=> 'access_token',
        'title' => 'Video Title',
        'source'=> new CURLFile("$pathtofile", 'video/mp4'));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.2/pageid/videos');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a Graph API Call like this:

```
curl \
-F "title=Video Title" \
-F "access_token=page_access_token_with_publish_actions_permission" \
-F "source=@/path/to/my_video.MOV" \
"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.2/page_id/videos"
```

Worked as expected. Just to mess around with it, instead of publishing to graph-video.facebook.com, I tried uploading to graph.facebook.com. Both videos I uploaded were sent to my videos album.

[image: My Page's videos]

I would try doing the same CURL call, with the video you're trying to upload and see if it works that way.

Comment: @studente100 I would also verify that you are indeed using a Page Access Token. If this is still not working, I would file a bug report on developers.facebook.com/bugs, giving detailed reproduction steps (both PHP and plain CURL), the Access Token you're using to make this request, and link to this StackOverflow question.